# Issue Regarding How to Put Aspect ratio in Ios.

Tags: ios, iphone, aspect-ratio

[image: This is What i want to display.]
As there is super View in that Super there is another View having Height 100 and width 270. i have given constraints like this for inner view (Image) Given Top =5, Leading and Trailing 25 25 and Aspect ratio 320:100(Width of Super View and Height of Inner View), When i add this constraints then size of inner view changes accordingly Means Works Fine. But when I add TextField and Label inside View then Size of label and Textfield Not changes Accordingly Please Specify me what aspect ratio I give To Label and TextField. Please  Thank You

Comment: you want both text field at same size correct ?

Comment: screen shot of expected result??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect Ratio is used for like as the width increases the height of that particular object also increases with that ratio vice versa case if height increases but giving an object just aspect ratio doesnt mean that the objects dimension will increase/decrease automatically, you have to give other related constraints also to make your object's dimension change as the view's dimension chnage liek for example giving proportional height or width to that object with respect to the view then as the view increases or decreases the dimension of that object will also change.

[image]

Give equal height to the  container
[image]

Set the multiplier
[image]

The same you do with textField and with bottom label you give Leading Training equal Height and vertical space with the top label and In textfield also the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Click the second UITextField drag it to first set leading ,trailing
>   ,equal height ,equal width.
>
> Then set horizontal space to second label.
>
> This constraints make it proper .
>
> If you want aspect ration drag with in the UITextField set height
>   constraints and width constraints (or)Aspect ratio Constraints.